# How to Handle duplicate tweet error in ios 6

Tags: ios

I handled tweet cancel and completed condition in its completion block it is working and when i send duplicate tweet it show duplicate tweet error message ok fine but my problem is just after duplicate error it shows tweet is completed message so i want to stop tweet completed message in case of Duplicate error message please solve my problem. here is my working code.

```
self.tweetSheet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [self.tweetSheet setInitialText:@"Some message."];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:self.tweetSheet animated:YES];
    // Called when the tweet dialog has been closed
    self.tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result)
    {
        NSString * msg;
        if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
        {
                msg = @"Tweet compostion was canceled.";
        }
        else if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
        {
            NSLog(@"result %d",result);
                msg = @"Tweet composition completed.";
        }

         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tweet Status" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        // Show alert to see how things went...
        [self.tweetSheet dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        // Dismiss the controller
       };
}
```

Comment: Have you found Solution  for this Problem

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add a boolean value? `repeated = FALSE`, and switch it to `TRUE` when the first message appears. Then in your completion handler block just verify

```
    else if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone && repeated != TRUE) {            

        NSLog(@"result %d",result);

        msg = @"Tweet composition completed.";

}
```